# How can I suppress the debug output of Capistrano

Tags: capistrano3

I am using Capistrano 3 and I have no idea how to suppress the debug output

here is my task

```
namespace :install do
  task :download do
    on roles(:app) do
      execute("wget http://dl.bintray.com/groovy/maven/groovy-binary-2.2.2.zip")
    end
  end
end
```

and here is how I start the script

```
$ cap --quiet development install:download
```

and this is the spammy output

```
INFO [45917f64] Running /usr/bin/env wget http://dl.bintray.com/groovy/maven/groovy-binary-2.2.2.zip on 192.168.33.10
DEBUG [45917f64] Command: wget http://dl.bintray.com/groovy/maven/groovy-binary- 2.2.2.zip
DEBUG [45917f64]    --2014-04-16 07:11:53--  http://dl.bintray.com/groovy/maven/groovy-binary-2.2.2.zip
DEBUG [45917f64]    Resolving dl.bintray.com (dl.bintray.com)...
DEBUG [45917f64]    5.153.24.114
DEBUG [45917f64]    Connecting to dl.bintray.com (dl.bintray.com)|5.153.24.114|:80...
DEBUG [45917f64]    connected.
DEBUG [45917f64]    HTTP request sent, awaiting response...
DEBUG [45917f64]    200 OK
DEBUG [45917f64]    Length: 29713408 (28M) [application/zip]
DEBUG [45917f64]    Saving to: `groovy-binary-2.2.2.zip.8'
DEBUG [45917f64]
DEBUG [45917f64]         0K .....
DEBUG [45917f64]    .
DEBUG [45917f64]    ..
DEBUG [45917f64]    .. ...
```

I also tried to put this at various parts in the code

```
SSHKit.config.output_verbosity=Logger::ERROR
```

still I am overwhelemed with DEBUG outputs.

Answer (score 4):

OK - this was simple

```
# Default value for :log_level is :debug
set :log_level, :error
```

Comment: Any way to do it using command line environment variables or switches?